# ObservableCollection and CollectionChanged Event

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Why does the collectionchanged event not fire in the following code, yet I can see the new instance of InventoryBTO I add to the ObservableCollection?

```
 private ObservableCollection<InventoryBTO> _inventoryRecords;
    public ObservableCollection<InventoryBTO> InventoryRecords
    {
        get { return _inventoryRecords; }
        set { _inventoryRecords = value; }
    }

    private InventoryBTO _selectedRecord;
    public InventoryBTO SelectedRecord
    {
        get { return _selectedRecord; }
        set 
        {
            if (_selectedRecord != value)
            {
                _selectedRecord = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedRecord"));
            }
        }
    }

    public InventoryViewModel()
    {
        if (_inventoryRecords == null)
        {
            InventoryRecords = new ObservableCollection<InventoryBTO>();
            this.InventoryRecords.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(InventoryRecords_CollectionChanged);
        }

        _inventoryRecords = InventoryListBTO.GetAllInventoryRecords();
    }

    void InventoryRecords_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: looks like you hook up to the collection in your ctor and then immediately overwrite the reference with a totally different collection.  Perhaps you instead meant to do an AddRange instead of overwriting?  Either way, the observable collection you created and then hooked up to is long gone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning your private member to a new instance of an `ObservableCollection` that you're getting back from your method. Therefore, what's happening is, you're hooking up to the event of one collection, but then blowing away that instance and replacing it with a new instance you never hooked up an event handler to. Here's what you can do. Create a class that inherits from `ObservableCollection` and adds an addrange method:

```
public class RangeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private bool supressEvents = false;

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        supressEvents = true;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            base.Add(item);
        }
        this.supressEvents = false;
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, items.ToList()));

    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.surpressEvents)
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can change your class to this:

```
private RangeObservableCollection<InventoryBTO> _inventoryRecords;
public RangeObservableCollection<InventoryBTO> InventoryRecords
{
    get { return _inventoryRecords; }
    set { _inventoryRecords = value; }
}

private InventoryBTO _selectedRecord;
public InventoryBTO SelectedRecord
{
    get { return _selectedRecord; }
    set 
    {
        if (_selectedRecord != value)
        {
            _selectedRecord = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedRecord"));
        }
    }
}

public InventoryViewModel()
{
    if (_inventoryRecords == null)
    {
        InventoryRecords = new ObservableCollection<InventoryBTO>();
        this.InventoryRecords.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(InventoryRecords_CollectionChanged);
    }

    this.InventoryRecords.AddRange(InventoryListBTO.GetAllInventoryRecords());
}

void InventoryRecords_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //e.NewItems will be an IList of all the items that were added in the AddRange method...
}
```

Comment: First line pointed about my problem. So I added CollectionChanged event handler on setter of of property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ObservableCollection<InventoryBTO> InventoryRecords
{
    get { return _inventoryRecords; }
    set 
    { 
      _inventoryRecords = value; 
      onPropertyChanged(this, "InventoryRecords");

    }
 }
```

OR

```
public ObservableCollection<InventoryBTO> InventoryRecords
{
    get { return _inventoryRecords; }
    set 
    { 
      _inventoryRecords = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("InventoryRecords"));

    }
 }
```

Depending on your implementation.

Comment: whenever a value is set to a property, the method “onPropertyChanged” will be called which in turn raises the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: I don't understand.  How does the PropertyChanged Event affect the CollectionChanged event of the collection when a new InventoryBTO is added?

Comment: Also how would you then access the properties inside the collection changed event which contain the new items added.

Comment: CollectionChanged event Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx

Comment: Correct, so why when I add an item to the observable collection does the event not fire?  Am I totally missing the point?