# Using LinQ to filter ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a MVVM application and I am trying to make filtering through LinQ work on my ObservableCollection that is gotten from database based on Entity Framework.

In View Model I have this:

```
public class MenuListViewModel : BaseViewModelCollection<Menu>

{
    private string filterString;

    public string FilterString
    {
        get { return filterString; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, filterString)) return;
            filterString = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //TODO problems with notification, filter doesn't work
    public ObservableCollection<Menu> FilteredItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (filterString == null) return Items; //Items is Observable Collection that contains every Item
            var query = Items.Where(x => x.Time.ToString().StartsWith(filterString));
            return new ObservableCollection<Menu>(query);
        }
    }

    public MenuListViewModel(MenuService menuService)
    {
        base.Service = menuService; //Using IoC to get service
    }
}
```

In Xaml I have the following Binding:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="RecipeFilterBox" Margin="5,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FilterString, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Grid.Column="1" Height="47.07" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

The thing is that when I write anything in the TextBox, nothing changes. I know that there is something wrong with the propertyChanged event, but I really can't figure out how to fix this. If you need any more information about this app, just ask me.

EDIT:
The xaml for FilteredItems looks like this:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="MenuItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding DeletedItem, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Foreground="#FFFFEDD3" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18.667" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle1}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Recipe.Name}" Width="255"/>
                    <TextBlock Width="175" Text="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource EnumTimeToItsDescriptionValueConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: You need to register the event with '+=' in the constructor.

Comment: Register it to what specifically? can u be more specific?

Comment: See answer 2 at following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042179/observablecollection-and-collectionchanged-event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve this using [`ICollectionView`](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html).

use `FilteredItems` as the underlying source of the `ICollectionView` and expose `ICollectionView` to your view instead of `ObservableCollection<Menu>`

Use the filter delegate to provide the filter logic

```
FilteredItems.Filter = item =>
{
    Menu m = item as Menu;
    return m.Time.ToString().StartsWith(FilterString);
}
```

and when `FilterString` changes invoke `FilterItems.Refresh();`

Here is an example:

```
public class MenuListViewModel : BaseViewModelCollection<Menu>
{
   public MenuListViewModel()
   {
      var data = new List<Menu> { some data ... }; // your real list of menus
      // initialize the collection view
      FilteredItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(data);
      // apply filtering delegate
      FilteredItems.Filter = i =>
      {
         // This will be invoked for every item in the underlying collection 
         // every time Refresh is invoked
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterString)) return true;
         Menu m = i as Menu;
         return m.Time.ToString().StartsWith(FilterString);
      };
   }

   private string filterString;
   public string FilterString
   {
       get { return filterString; }
       set
       {
           if (Equals(value, filterString)) return;
           filterString = value;
           FilteredItems.Refresh(); // tirggers filtering logic
           RaisePropertyChanged("FilterString"); 
       }
   }

    public ICollectionView FilteredItems { get; set; }
}
```

You would also have to change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on your filter `TextBox` to make it update the `FilterString` every time the user changes the text.

```
Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ...}
```

Comment: It's alot of new stuff on me, can u be more specific on how to apply this in my application?

Comment: How should I add the ICollectionView to the class?
I suppose that, public ICollectionView FilteredItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items); is not the right way.

Comment: @Dracke I've uploaded a full example. Hope this helps

Comment: I have one issue with this now, Instead of data I am using Items, which is Observable Collection, that contains class Menu with several properties. One of the properties is Time. How can i force the i in the filter to care only about the time? Right now, I dont really now what it filters but probably some reference.

Comment: @Dracke `i` is an item in the underlying collection, in your case a `Menu` object. just cast it and use it to extract the propery you want. I've updated the example

Answer (score 0):

Add `RaisePropertyChanged("FilteredItems")` inside `FilterString` setter. `FilteredItems` property changed is never raised so bindings doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I changed the RaisePropertyChanged(); in the FilterString to RaisePropertyChanged("FilteredItems"); but the filter is stil not working at all. The "FilteredItems" is also underlined (maybe by resharper) telling that the Explicit argument passed to parameter with caller info attribute.